# VB.net dropdown list value populated in variable rather than text

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list populated as follows:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubgroup" runat="server" cssclass="dropdown" style="font-size: 11px" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select All</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="GenF">Girls</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="GenM">Boys</asp:ListItem>
-----snip
```

In my page load procedure I have declared a variable and then use that variable to update the contents of a label:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim strSubgroup As String = ddlSubgroup.Text

    lblHeaderSubroup.Text = " " & strSubgroup
```

However, this results in the dropdown listitem value eg "GenF" displaying in my label and not the text eg Girls as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try referring to the `lblHeaderSubroup.SelectedItem.Text` property instead of the object itself.

This could be where you're experiencing the issue.

Comment: Westie @AVD Thanks both. I gave the answer to Westie as he pipped AVD to the post.

Comment: LOL! Thanks Matt.  I'll give AVD a +1 to balance up!  ;o)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ddlSubgroup.SelectedItem.Text` property.

```
lblHeaderSubroup.Text = ddlSubgroup.SelectedItem.Text
```